# Media player in android to play audio stored in emulator sdcard

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, android-mediaplayer, android-sdcard, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying play music that is stored in emulator sdcard,but the music is unable to play,below is my code,please tell me what is wrong with this code.
I am getting following error:

> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

thank you,

```
 play_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Onclick");
                mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                String media_path= "sdcard/sample_music.mp3";
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                Uri uri= Uri.parse(media_path);
                Log.d(TAG,"Player initiated");
                try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playback started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        play_btn.setEnabled(false);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                            play_btn.setEnabled(true);
                            mediaPlayer.release();
                            mediaPlayer = null;
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Playback finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

        });
```

Comment: set `media_path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sample_music.mp3"`

Comment: @ak sacha,I tried with that also its not playing,and also have checked whether song is correctly stored in sdcard.

Comment: I am getting error like  Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Answer (score 0):

Uri looks not valid.

valid Uri has a prefix like "content://" "file://"

[My app](https://github.com/roshad/MusicRo) for self use may help you. Very simple, only 2 classes.